# AWS Assume Role access denied while using AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, sts-securitytokenservice, aws-php-sdk

I have a problem using the AWS PHP SDK
when calling AssumeRole from the apache server (PHP SDK) the following error appears

```
    Error executing "AssumeRole" on "https://sts.amazonaws.com"; 
    AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sts.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` 
response: Sender AccessDeni (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access denied - Sender AccessDenied Access denied
```

I tested the command to assume role in the same ec2 machine using AWS CLI and it works fine.

Here is the code That I used.

```
const AccessKey = "<AccessKey>";
    const SecretAccessKey = "<SecretAccessKey>";
    const AccountID = "<AccountID>";
    const Name_space = "default";  // leave this as default

    use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
    use Aws\Sts\StsException;     

 try {
  $sts = new Aws\Sts\StsClient([
            'region' => 'us-east-1',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials  ' => array('key' => AccessKey,
               'secret' => SecretAccessKey)
        ]);



 $session = $sts->assumeRole([
           'DurationSeconds' => 900,
           'RoleArn' => '<arn>', // REQUIRED
           'RoleSessionName' => testSession, // REQUIRED
      ]);

 } catch (Exception $e) {

        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
```

--EDITED to add the following--

the user dose have a policy to assume the role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "<role arn>"
    }
}
```

and this is the trust relationship for the role

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "<user arn>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does your IAM user have permission to assume the role? If so, can you check if the IAM role's trust relationship allows the IAM user to assume the role?

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 yes I have the premission to assume role and the trust relationship allows the IAM user to assume the role. please take a look I added them. is it possible that I have to add trust relationship for the SDK or API ?

Comment: Please ensure that the IAM User's ARN in the trust relationship is correct. What you have done so far is correct. Try running the following command to ensure that there is nothing wrong with the permissions: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="" aws sts assume-role --role-arn iam_role_arn --role-session-name Session1`. If this command returns the credentials, then there is something wrong with the code. If not, check your IAM user permissions and IAM role permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Open role in AWS console > Trust Relationship.
Click on "Edit Trust Relationship" and paste the following

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::014361779291:user/<<username>>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```